# Is Static NAT and Port Forwarding the same thing?

Tags: nat

I am reading about Static NAT and Port Forwarding, these two concepts seem to be the same thing, are they the same thing?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: @DavidPostill After reading more about Static NAT and Port Forwarding, I think there is a difference between Static NAT and Port Forwarding, which is that in Static NAT the port that is associated with the public IP can be different from the port that is associated with the private IP, while in Port Forwarding the port that is associated with the public IP is the same as the port that is associated with the private IP, Am I correct?

Comment: No you can forward an outside port number to a different inside port number.

Answer (score 0):

### Static NAT

Static NAT establishes a one to one relationship between two addresses (inside and outside). This allows the inside host to initiate traffic to the specified outside connection and receive responses (also the way around)

Example: You want to create a 1:1 connection between two specified services/devices and create a static NAT rule. You can initiate a connection from either of the devices

### Port Forwarding

Port Forwarding is usually used for incoming traffic to access an internal host.

Example: You want to access an FTP-Server on your private Network via Port 21. You'll set up a Port-Forwarding setting in the router/firewall for Port 21 and specify the internal IP. The Initiation of the connection comes from outside your network.